# How to show smileys added by keyboard like :-) or B-) in textview?

Tags: android, emoji

I have edittext from which I can add a comment.
I am able to convert smileys which are there in keyboard and I am able to show that in textview but problem is if i add :-) or B-) or some characters like this I dnt get emoji or smiley of that like we get in skype.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom TextView.
This library can be a good start point:
https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon